# How to redirect users to IE when content using Active X controls is opened with Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, microsoft-edge

Based on this link: [Edge redirecting to IE (at Reddit)](https://www.reddit.com/r/edge/comments/3guc3l/i_am_disappointed_edge_redirecting_to_ie/), there is apparently a way to show a special purpose page displaying:

> This website needs Internet Explorer This website uses technology that will work best in Internet Explorer.
>
> Open with Internet Explorer
>
> Keep going in Microsoft Edge

It will be very helpful for my applications using Active X controls. I already have code such as:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10;requiresActiveX=true" />
```

in all my head sections (added in the past to avoid the Metro style for Windows 8), but it doesn't do the trick (unlike what someone mentioned in the link above).

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is by including your site on the Enterprise Mode Site List so it will open in IE11 automatically:

The steps and the details can be found in this blog post by the Microsoft Edge team:

http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/08/26/how-microsoft-edge-and-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-10-work-better-together-in-the-enterprise/

Comment: Unfortunately we can ask it to thousands of users. The goal is that it works automatically for our customers without their IT having to deal about it.

Comment: You can reach out to Microsoft and ask that your site be added from either the IE or MS Edge CV List. The email is in here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but they say at this link that they will add it only if it

"Doesn't declare an "X-UA-Compatible-" meta tag or header"

anyway it looks like adding our sites to a centralized (MS managed) list is one possible solution (or even the only solution ?), I have now contacted Microsoft using the (hopefully) relevant email address iepo@microsoft.com, I'll report here if it resolved the issue or not

Comment: From the answer I got from the MS staff they are (very) reluctant to add sites to their Edge CV list, so this isn't a working solution after all.

One example provided by MS as good practice is this IKEA web site: 
http://kitchenplanner.ikea.com/US/UI/Pages/VPUI.htm

I suppose many developers will have to re-invent the wheel and localize messages instead of using the internationalized solution already existing, this looks pretty odd to me.

Comment: thanks for sharing...I think them sharing their email doesn't make any sense if they're not open in adding or removing the sites in the list after all