# Can't change the IE user agent, so need to add site domain to Microsoft Compatibility List

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, user-agent

We have a legacy c# web application facing compatibility issue in IE . it works with User-Agent = Mozilla/4.0...... but not User-Agent = Mozilla/5.0 (which is the default setting for IE 9+).

Add website domain in IE 'Compatibility View Settings' will change the user agent = Mozilla/4.0 and then fix the issue. But let our user to config their IE certainly don't make sense so we hope to add our site domain to Microsoft Compatibility List. Does anyone know how to do that?

We try X-UA meta tag but it won't change the user agent in the browser. Not sure if there is another work around.

Thank!

Comment: why wouldn't it work if the user agent string is different? what exactly happens?

Comment: @ Roman Canlas what happen is site get Server Error page. And it's fine with domain in the compatibility list.

Comment: maybe the server error had something to do with the c# code...

Comment: as for your question on how to add your site domain to the Microsoft list, please check my answer on a separate thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571929/how-to-redirect-users-to-ie-when-content-using-active-x-controls-is-opened-with/32572230#32572230

Comment: or to be direct, go here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That msdn link only tell you how to check if your website is on the compatibility list and how to remove from it.

Comment: you can also try asking them if they can add - iepo@microsoft.com